# More than 2 Origin and destination on Google Maps API 3

Tags: google-maps, google-api

I had this example :

> https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-panel

and I was wondering how to set routes by 2 or more waypoint? As you know on that application you can get the waypoint: first, set the origin / start point and then set the destination point and the maps will generating the routes. Script :

```
      function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
    var request = {
      origin: start,
      destination: end,
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
  }
```

see : origin : start, destination: end.

Now the Question is : Is that possible to me to set the waypoint by myself? Using LatLong from point-to-point or maybe I just say what the street name that will be the point?

Understand? Sorry I am not good at words but I always wait for the answers, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to add waypoints to a directions request:

Here is the description of the waypoint object from the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsWaypoint

Here is the request description in the documentation (see waypoints):
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRequest

[Example with an "address" waypoint](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypointsD.html)

[Example with a waypoint specified by coordinates](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypointsC.html)

Comment: do you mean this? : origin: "1521 NW 54th St, Seattle, WA 98107 "